# What can be the problem in response delay for api request, sometimes it takes 150 ms sometimes 8-9 seconds

Tags: node.js, iis, axios, pm2

Environment: Nodejs, axios, pm2, IIS, bepaid(online payments)

Nodejs hosted on IIS.

I use nodejs with api rote that use axios to send request to bepaid api

I measured the time before request and after and it takes sometimes 8-9 seconds.

I contacted with bepaid service team but they told me that the request to create a link for order takes around 50-100 ms for those requests that for me the request take 8-9 seconds.

How can it be?

Maybe there is an issue with IIS?

IIS Config

[image]

[image]

the api call code is:

[image]

What I tried:

1. I checked the load for apps(using cluster with pm2) and for the same app instance for 1 minute it can be 150ms to 9 seconds the api call to bepaid
2. Checked calling from different ips, locally, prod

I expect to find what is the issue

Comment: What takes 7-8 seconds? You have to make that very clearly. If you mean HTTP requests sent to `https://checkout.bepaid.by/ctp/api/checkouts`, unfortunately this isn't likely to be the right place for discussion. A lot can happen over the wire, and that's not what your Node.js code can control.

Comment: You can try to use failed request tracking to view the detailed request process. The log it generates will have the time spent on each request. You can view which stage takes too long.

Comment: @LexLi Just I want to know according to the environment I provided what cause the issue, and how to debug it? And the requests don't fail